# select * limit 100 equivalent in MongoDB using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am very new to MongoDB and using jupyter notebook for extracting data from mongodb. I am trying to fetch first 100 documents in MongoDB and i do have a crude way of fetching only 100 documents which is to add a counter and stop at 100th counter.

```
#import library
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

#connect with mongo client
client = MongoClient('myipaddress', 27011)

db = client.mydatabase_test
collection = db.mycollection_in_testdatabase

#start counter
i=0
for obj in collection.find():
    if i <= 100:
        print obj['dummy_column']
        i = i+1
    else:
        break
```

Is there any better way to do this in mongodb? I am sure there must be some equivalent of `select * from mydb limit 100` in mongodb. Can anyone help?

Comment: check **[limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit)**

Comment: @Yogesh, thats for mongodb shell and not pymongo

Comment: The `.find()` method returns a cursor object even if you use the [`limit`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.limit)which you need to consume using a for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yogesh said , you should use **limit**.
e.g.

```
cursor = collection.find().limit(100)
```

Now that you have created **cursor** you can extract some field like this:

```
something = []  # list for storing your 100 values of field dummy_column

for doc in cursor:   # loop through these 100 entries 

    something.append(doc.get('dummy_column', '')) # append to this list vallue of field **dummy_column**
```

Comment: I ran the exact code and this is what i got in output. `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor at 0x3a62c50>` I believe this is meant for mongodb shell and not pymongo?

Comment: So  put that cursor in loop.   e.g.

Comment: something = []
for doc in cursor:

    something.append(doc.get('some_field', ''))

Comment: It will add everything as there is no limit mentioned here. Can you give exact code? I do not want to run just any code unless sure as i do not want to do something that will write something that i don't want to.